# mongodb dropDatabase everyday

Tags: mongodb, digital-ocean

I'm have a mongodb installed in a droplet in digital ocean.
I was talking with de digital ocean suport right now, but, apparently he cant help me with this.

Checking mongodb logs, i see this:

> 2017-01-13T12:00:30.396+0000 I COMMAND  [conn29429] dropDatabase
>   MYDBNAME starting 2017-01-13T12:00:30.398+0000 I COMMAND  [conn29429]
>   dropDatabase MYDBNAME finished

And is repeating everyday, apparently.

I have no idea what is the cause, i dont have any cronjobs or any deleting operation in my applications.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: the same drop command is occurring for PLEASE_READ and README_MISSING_DATABASES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mongodb instance has been hacked, presumably because you've left it wide-open to the outside world.

There's a couple of articles here on the issue:

http://www.securityweek.com/multiple-attackers-hijacking-mongodb-databases-ransom
http://www.darknet.org.uk/2017/01/mongodb-ransack-33000-databases-hacked/z

You need to secure your mongodb instance

Comment: i has added the config security: authorization: enabled, to block anonymous access, i think this will solve, my fault.

Answer (score 1):

How is your database secured? It looks like you having security issues:
http://www.securityweek.com/multiple-attackers-hijacking-mongodb-databases-ransom